# Can PIL be used to get dimensions of an svg file?

Tags: python, image, svg, python-imaging-library

I have svg files which I would like to compare based on their dimensions.

I read about PIL as the best image tool in Python. Does PIL handle svg files? I can't seem to find this anywhere.

When Googling I saw people interpreting svg files as text which seems counterintuitive.

What if not PIL is be the best way to get the x & y dimensions of a .svg file?

Comment: People interpret SVG files as text because SVG files are actually XML text files that can be *interpreted* to render images.

Comment: You can try using [PySVG](http://codeboje.de/pysvg/)

Comment: using pysvg I have pysvg.parse(my file), however how can I get the x and y dimensions out? I am looking for clear documentation and I only see how to create svg not get info back out

Comment: pysvg when I installed using sudo easy_install pysvg as a pysvg.egg file and I couldn't use it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

PIL handles [many image types](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html), but not (yet?) SVG.  Partly, this is because SVG is a set of instructions to produce an image, not a container for raw image data.

Fortunately, SVG can be read as XML, using the tool of your choice; for example, [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) in the Python standard library.

Unfortunately, by its nature, SVG doesn't have a single native size.  Instead, [it has two size concepts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71568/is-there-any-concept-of-size-in-an-svg): the view box, and the height and width attributes.

If your svg file has `width` and `height` attributes, you can safely use those as the `x` and `y` dimensions, respectively.  Otherwise, if it has a `viewBox` attribute, it is meant to scale to any size you need it to; however, you can use its third and fourth numbers as width and height, if you need to.

Worse, SVG files could lack either one.  In that case, one could potentially compute a height and width based on the elements in the file, but that's trickier than anyone really wants to do, given the full capabilities of the format.